# "Drop button" só que com informações

Tags: html, css, button

Alguém pode me explicar como posso encontrar um tutorial sobre isto? eu procuro por "drop button" (oque faz sentido) mais não consigo encontrar algo relacionado a isto!

é um link (`<a>`) normal:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando clica em cima aparece algo que eu queira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara um link do tipo `<a>` seria melhor para te levar para outra página ou algo assim. Da forma que vc precisa acho que o melhor seria um checkbox ou até mesmo um ul>li algum script para mostrar a informação. A tag `<a>` acredito não ser a melhor opção...

Comment: Se quiser algo só com CSS me fala que te ajudo.

Comment: Valeu,  eu só precisava dessa informação mesmo.